# Unable to use filter or edit Excel Worksheet while opening from Excel web access?

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-enterprise, excel, excel-services, secure-store

I am able to view and filter data based off excel fileters via the Excel Web Access web part for Excel workbooks.

However, when I "open in Excel" it does not allow me to filter or edit. 
Note: I have created an Secure store ID for the workbooks and they work just fine

Please advise.

Here are the screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you specify the workbooks to use the Secure Store Service ID in the data connection? It should be under the authentication settings...

[image]

Comment: Yes I did. If I hadnt then it wouldnt show up in the Excel web access web part in the first place.

Comment: Are you using a SQL Server account login for the Secure Store Service Application ID?

Comment: Regardless, does the Secure Store Service Application identity have proper access to the SSAS or SQL database it's trying to reach?

Comment: yes i am using a service account that does have access to the database. Like I mentioned before, if the service account and the SSID werent configured properly it wouldnt open and would throw an error while opening up in the Excel web access web part.

Comment: The error it's giving you is specific to permissions, if it was set up correctly, it wouldn't be throwing that error. What authentication is your front-end using?

Comment: Claims based authentication. And it seems to be working on my colleagues computer just fine. He is looking at the same work book and is able to open in excel and filter or edit.

Comment: Try to look into Excel Trusted settings, and make sure your IE settings are set to defaults.